# FullSimplify with assumptions

Tags: simplifying-expressions

Is there a way to write a `FullSimplify` at the end of the line with some assumptions?

That is, if I write

```
a^2+b^2+2 a b //FullSimplify[...]
```

is there any way to include some assumptions for a,b?

Comment: `... //FullSimplify[#, ...]&`

Answer (score 7):

Use

```
Assuming[a > 0, a^2 + b^2 + 2 a b // FullSimplify]
```

or

```
a^2 + b^2 + 2 a b // FullSimplify[#, a > 0] &
```